# app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, nodemon

I am getting this error in my reactjs project when I am running gulp command. The project shows that it compiled successfully but nodemon app crashes and therefore I am not able to view my application running.

P.S. I am on mac and when I used to run it on ubuntu vmware I used to compile it without any errors.

This is the error when I run gulp

```
[00:18:43] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[00:18:43] Requiring external module babel-register
[00:18:44] Using gulpfile ~/Frontend1.0/gulpfile.babel.js
[00:18:44] Starting 'build:watch'...
[00:18:44] Starting 'copy:assets'...
[00:18:44] Starting 'copy:vendors'...
  Cleaned build/ 
  Copied 12 asset entries.
[00:18:44] Finished 'copy:vendors' after 376 ms
[00:18:44] Starting 'copy:views'...
[00:18:44] copied views all files 19.75 kB
[00:18:44] Finished 'copy:views' after 102 ms
[00:18:44] Starting 'copy:public'...
[00:18:45] Finished 'copy:public' after 222 ms
[00:18:45] Finished 'copy:assets' after 702 ms
[00:18:45] Starting 'bundle:dll'...
DLL Bundled.
Hash: 45f26d608c690be6e6c5
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 4097ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
dll.vendor.js  3.11 MB       0  [emitted]  vendor
[00:18:49] Finished 'bundle:dll' after 4.13 s
[00:18:49] Starting 'bundle'...
Hash: 7457a3cd38cf5c991640
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 638ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server-bundle.js  37.3 kB       0  [emitted]  main
  -- server:watch bundled.
Hash: 4535205365b3c29afb82
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 38097ms
         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main-bundle.js  20.1 MB       0  [emitted]  main
  -- client bundled.
[00:19:27] Finished 'bundle' after 38 s
[00:19:27] Starting 'start:server'...
Starting Node Server...
[00:19:27] Finished 'start:server' after 37 ms
[00:19:27] Starting 'watch:sync'...
[00:19:27] [nodemon] 1.11.0
[00:19:27] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[00:19:27] [nodemon] watching: build/server-bundle.js
[00:19:27] [nodemon] starting `node --debug build/server-bundle.js`
Server Restarted: Reloading BrowserSync.
(node:7437) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.
[00:19:27] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[tessact: ] Proxying: http://localhost:4200
[tessact: ] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.0.32:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.0.32:3001
 -------------------------------------
[tessact: ] Watching files...
[00:19:27] Finished 'watch:sync' after 211 ms
[00:19:27] Starting 'watch:assets'...
[00:19:27] Finished 'watch:assets' after 107 ms
[00:19:27] Finished 'build:watch' after 43 s
[00:19:27] Starting 'default'...
[00:19:27] Finished 'default' after 41 μs
webpack built 4535205365b3c29afb82 in 25604ms
Hash: 4535205365b3c29afb82
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 25604ms
         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
main-bundle.js  20.1 MB       0       main
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Is it because of the first line of the snippet? Or is it because of something else? And How should I solve it? I tried closing the project and re opening it, I also tried npm install again.

**Update:** I have solved "Failed to load external module @babel/register" by downgrading gulp version from 3.9.1 to 3.9.0. But the nodemon app crash is still there.

Is it because of node version? I am having 9.4.0 node version

Comment: Can try downgrading your node 8.9.4?

Comment: No progress by this also

Comment: What does the console say when you hit your app in browser? Also there is deprecation warning in your snippet? --debug has been deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

After so many hit and trials I solved it by downgrading the node version I was using. I downgraded from 9.4.0 to 6.9.1 and the app started working. Hope this would save someone's efforts.